# how to take user direct input in non english language(ex. hindi) in textbox on the form

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

i want to create non-English lingual(ex. in Hindi) web forms that is take user input in Hindi.
As i am developing web application i want such setting that user or client  can easily enter character in non-English language...My questions are as follows for this..
1)
Is this possible and how can i create such web pages that make it possible
2)
can i have to do for this client side or browser side or it can be done without any setting
3)
Have i required that non-language font on the client side or such facility can be available in web applications.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this by help of that language font, in your case you can use `shivaji font`.

I think shivaji font is for devnagari script.i have used this font for Marathi(indian sub state language) language fonts.

you have to install these fonts on client-side,download from anywhere,just go through below step

1) Download and Unzip the downloaded package in one folder. ( You may do it on desktop ). 
2) Now goto `My Computer –> C: –> WINDOWS –> FONTS` folder Path will be like this in “C:\WINDOWS\Fonts”

3) Now open Fonts directory from Desktop and copy all 3 font and paste them in “C:\WINDOWS\Fonts” directory.
4) You done it. All fonts will get installed in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the encoding to `UTF-8` in the globalization element of your web.config as shown:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

If you want to make custom textbox control that only needs to take input as Hindi.

Here is an article based for that :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67944/Hindi-Marathi-Transliteration-ASP-NET-Custom-Contr

Comment: hi..i set globalization but as i enter a character it is enter into english and i want such thing that as user enter a character that is in hindi character...for that what can i do.?

Comment: For that you need create your own user control which is the second option I gave you.

Comment: can you provide some other link for that..i coudn't understand on above link.

Comment: Here is another link for you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301832/Custom-Text-box-Control-that-Switch-keyboard-langu